# React: Receiving same value for different inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `handleChangeUpdate` function works for a single input which for example is `name`.

But when adding a second input such as `description`, both inputs receive the same value regardless of typing in `name` or `description` input.

**How do I let every input receives it own value ?**

```js
const F = () => {

  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "a",
      name: "John",
      description: "1as23"
    },
    {
      id: "b",
      name: "Eric",
      description: "12ce3"
    },
    {
      id: "c",
      name: "Jonathan",
      description: "12vt3"
    },
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = React.useState("");

  function handleChangeUpdate(id, value, description) {
    const newList = list.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        const updatedItem = {
            ...item,
            name: value,
            description: value
          };
   
        return updatedItem;
      }
      return item;
    });
 
    setList(newList);
    console.log(newList);
  }
 
  return (
    <div>                
        <ul >             
            <div>
                {list.map((item) => (                                                                    
                    <li key={item.id}>                      
                    <input className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> handleChangeUpdate(item.id, e.target.name)} defaultValue={item.name}></input>
                    <input className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> handleChangeUpdate(item.id, e.target.description)} defaultValue={item.description}></input>
                    </li>
                    ))}                   
            </div>               
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<F />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: `const [name, setName] = React.useState("");` creates a *single* string in your state, but your list has *three* objects. That's not going to work. Plus, `e.target` is your `<input>` element, and all yours has is `.value`. There's is no  `e.target.description` for instance.

Comment: My approach to this would be to make a <li> component that gets passed down the list element and a function to change it.

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry I'm still a complete beginner in React. I didn't understand what does  three objects have to do with the state. I mean when I'm passing only `name` along with `id`, it works. But not for multiple inputs.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you have these unused states and I didn't see you're pretty close to solving this (without even using them). You need something like `onChange={(e)=> handleChangeUpdate(item.id, "name", e.target.value)}`. Then you use `function handleChangeUpdate(id, key, newValue)` to handle the change.

Comment: Or you do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-sun-gv1ys?file=/src/App.js (making a person's <li> its own component)

Comment: You are close, follow @ChrisG's suggestions, just wanted to add that the `console.log(newList);` after the state update won't log the updated state, but rather the state from the current render cycle. It's an issue you'd hit after getting the update straightened out.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much. While it's working perfectly, I'm will take some time to understand because I'm still learning. Thanks again.